# Github Actions OWASP ZAP full vs API scan

Tags: owasp, zap, cicd, devsecops

Is the api scan included in the full scan for the OWASP ZAP Action Full Scan for Github Actions? I need to know if I need to include a separate scan for APIs, or if its already covered by the full scan.

Answer (score 1):

The API scan allows you to import a specified API definition. The full scan does not have that option. If ZAP finds an API definition as part of the spidering then it will import it.